# Using function on entire pandas dataframe to generate comments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiple dataframes which are similar to below:

```
df:
Name    Value1  Value2
A       98      57
B       267     962
C       43      423
D       612     34
```

I need to use a function on the above datframe which will perform some calculations and output some variables.

```
def my_func()
    c001=[]
    for _, value in df.iterrows():
        var1 = value['Value1']
        var2 = value['Value1%']
        seg1 = value['Name']
        flag1 = 'over' if var1>0 else 'under'
        kpi = 'YYT'
        c001.append(f"{seg1} {kpi} {flag1} Plan by {human(var1)}({abs(var2)}%) ")
    c001[1]
```

How do I use this function on the input dataframe to print the value in variable `c001[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly:

```
def my_func()
    c001=[]
    for _, value in df.iterrows():
        var1 = value['Value1']
        var2 = value['Value1%']
        seg1 = value['Name']
        flag1 = 'over' if var1>0 else 'under'
        kpi = 'YYT'
        c001.append(f"{seg1} {kpi} {flag1} Plan by {human(var1)}({abs(var2)}%) ")
    return c001[1]

print (my_func())
```

Comment: so if i have multiple dataframes say df1, df2, df3 , how do i use this same function without writing the dataframe name in the function?

Comment: You can send the DF to the function

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. This function that I wrote above was a very simplified version. I have multiple such statements generated in the function. Is it possible to have multiple return statements at the end of the function so that it returns 4-5 statements instead of only one?

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create "c001" as a column and then print it.

```
def my_func(value):
    var1 = value['Value1']
    var2 = value['Value1%']
    seg1 = value['Name']
    flag1 = 'over' if var1 > 0 else 'under'
    kpi = 'YYT'
    return f"{seg1} {kpi} {flag1} Plan by {human(var1)}({abs(var2)}%) "

df["c001"] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)

print(df["c001"])
```

The result will look like:

```
0      A YYT over Plan by 98(57%) 
1    B YYT over Plan by 267(962%) 
2     C YYT over Plan by 43(423%) 
3     D YYT over Plan by 612(34%) 
Name: c001, dtype: object
```